# how can i deactivate the Flask-WTForms submit-button textdecoration?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, materialize, flask-wtforms

I'm looking for a way to give my submit field of flaskWTF

```
submit = SubmitField('text')
```

the Design of the common materialize button:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
    text
</button>
```

I use the same CSS classes of Materialize as I did with the button but somehow the text is black instead of white, has a blue border on-click and only to click the inner of the blue border have an effect.

```
{{ form.submit(class="btn waves-effect waves-light") }}
```

The white colour of the text is not the main problem but does not look very nice. But the problem is that blue border around the text which is the only clickable area of the button.

Does someone know how to help me? I hope I did everything right this is my first post on this page.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution: i had to delete the classes `waves-effect` and `waves-light`